# C++ Two distinct strings with the same 40 bit hash value

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, hash

I am having some trouble with an assignment, I am to create an algorithm for a given function that takes a string and turns it into a 40 bit hash. With this, I must find two distinct hashes that have the same value. The TA gave us a hint about using the birthday paradox to find the amount of distinct strings before I get a reasonable probability. My question is,how should I approach this given no strings and no set length they must be.

Comment: `int hash(std::string str) { return 0x00000000001; }`. You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the hint about the "birthday paradox" (which is not a paradox at all,) I'm assuming your assignment requires you to generate many strings and hash them and find two that collide.

Since you are using a 40-bit hash function, you'd expect to have to try 2<sup>20</sup> strings (on average) to find that first collision. One way to approach it is generating and hashing any and every string you can, with a length of zero and upwards.

One way to do that would be something like this: (I haven't actually tried any of this code.)

```
using std::string;

template <typename F>
bool GenAllStrings_Worker (string & s, unsigned idx, string const & char_set,
                           unsigned long long & cnt, F f)
{
    if (idx >= s.size())
        return f(s, ++cnt);

    for (auto c : char_set)
    {
        s[idx] = c;
        if (GenAllStrings_Worker(s, idx + 1, char_set, cnt, f))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// Continues generating successively longer strings until "f" returns true.
// Passes each generated string and number of strings generated so far to "f".
template <typename F>
void GenAllStrings (string const & char_set, F f)
{
    unsigned long long cnt = 0;

    for (unsigned len = 0; ; ++len)
    {
        string s (len, '?');
        if (GenAllStrings_Worker (s, 0, char_set, cnt, f))
            return;
    }
}
```

And you could use it like this: (don't forget that you need to provide `hash_code` type and the `MyHashFunction` function.)

```
std::unordered_map<hash_code, string> generated_hashes;

GenAllStrings ("abcdef...ABCD...0123...whatever",
    [&](string const & s, unsigned long long cnt){
        hash_code h = MyHashFunction(s);
        if (generated_hashes.find(h) != generated_hashes.end())
        {
            std::cout << "#" << cnt << " - Found a collision: '" << s <<"'"
                 << " collides with '" << generated_hashes[h] << "'"
                 << ", with a hash of " << h << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
        h[h] = s;
        return false;
    });
```

I've written the lambda I pass into the `GenAllStrings` function to stop after the first collision; but you can generate however many collisions you want (or have time for,) stop after you reached a certain length of strings, etc.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Compile error? What? Because I just tried it with some simple test cases and it seemed to work.

Comment: at: for (auto c : char_set)

Comment: This is C++ code. You are probably using an old and non-standard compiler (i.e. not supporting C++11.) Use a current compiler (or make sure you are passing the right switches to the one you got.) Here's the code that compiles and runs: http://ideone.com/vvjXsw

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you apply the birthday paradox, how many random strings do you need in order for there to be a significant probability that 2 of those strings will have the same 40-bit hash?

Why not write a program that generates that many strings, and try to find a collision?